# Regex help needed

Tags: asp.net, regex, validation

I have to validate two asp.net text boxes. First one has input as :

"temp-xxxx" or "perm-xxxx" (note: here xxxx are digits. Strings to be validated are in the double quotes.The quotes are not needed to be validated.)

Second textbox input is a list:

temp-xxxx, temp-xxxx, temp-xxxx (x are numerics)

I need these two regex. Please help me out.

I am using regex validator for each text box. These two text boxes are not dependents. they are separate. Please help me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try these

1.

```
^(?:temp|perm)-\d{4}$
```

`^` Start of the string

`(?:temp|perm)` "temp" or "perm"

`\d` a digit

`{4}` 4 times

2.

```
^temp-\d{4}(?:,\stemp-\d{4})*$
```

`(?:,\stemp-\d{4})*` Match `,\stemp-\d{4}` 0 or more times

`\s` is a whitespace

Comment: perfect..you are the regex god